# Using Modules to Include Files in the Solution

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am working on sharepoint project and trying to include jquery tabs.
I added jquery.js, jquery-ui.css and jquery-ui.js using module and this is what Module1 file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="Module1">
    <File Path="Module1\jquery.js" Url="Module1/jquery.js" />
    <File Path="Module1\jquery-ui.css" Url="Module1/jquery-ui.css" />
    <File Path="Module1\jquery-ui.js" Url="Module1/jquery-ui.js" />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

After this, how do I refer those files in xxxxUserControl.ascx file?

thanks,

Comment: Why don`t you use a mapped (layouts) folder?

Comment: this worked:<SharePoint:ScriptLink id="ScriptLink2" runat="server" Localizable="false" Name="AdminDashBoard/js/jquery.js" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink id="ScriptLink1" runat="server" Localizable="false" Name="AdminDashBoard/js/jquery-ui.js" />

<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration1" runat="server" Name="_layouts/15/AdminDashBoard/css/jquery-ui.css" />

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="Module1" Url="SiteAssets">
    <File Path="Module1\jquery-1.12.4.js" Url="Module1/jquery-1.12.4.js" Type="GhostableInLibrary"/>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

Reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/Module1/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try that if the above method causes an issue.